# NumberFormatException on eclipse start

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm a novice at Java and eclipse IDE. I'm trying to create a plugin to my installed eclipse 4.4.0 by [the official IBM article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html).
I've added plug-in description to the plugin.xml:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
    <launchConfigurationType
        name="MyConfiguration"
        delegate="com.myplugin.first.launching.MyLaunchConfiguration"
        modes="run, debug"               
        id="com.myplugin.first.launching.myConfiguration">        
    </launchConfigurationType>
</extension>
```

and I've created empty configuration delegate with required dependencies.
Unfortunately I cannot launch a new eclipse application with my plugin because every time I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:1747)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:1764)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.(Storage.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.(Equinox.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:232)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
    An error has occurred. See the log file
    null.
```

I have not found the log file with the error.
What's wrong? What should I do?

Maybe somebody knows the problem.

Comment: What version number did you give your plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I,ve fixed the problem. I just created a new workspace and copied my project and config files to the workspace.

So the problem was in a broken workspace. I guess some workspace config file was corrupted. Anyway thank redoc for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting everything in `eclipse\configuration` folder except `config.ini` and start your eclipse. Also paste the contents of the latest log file from `eclipse\configuration` for complete error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've removed everything as you said but no result. My eclipse didn't want to start. just said: Eclipse An error has occurred. See the log file...

Comment: can you paste the latest log file from `eclipse\configuration` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (with same stack trace).
I solved the problem by deleting (renaming actually) the `configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager` folder.

The key was the hint in the stack trace `org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage`

After restarting with `eclipse -clean`, eclipse started fine and recreated the folder.

I have to say we're using a very old version of eclipse:

```
Version: Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)
Build id: M20171130-0510
```