# java.lang.NumberFormatException on Eclipse start

Tags: eclipse

When I start Eclipse, I sometimes get the following error:

```
!SESSION Wed Dec 16 09:31:26 EST 2015    ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-12-16 09:31:26.409
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getLastKnownConfigIniBaseTimestamp(Main.java:1966)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.processConfiguration(Main.java:1905)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

A similar error with a different call stack and cause is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26216142/25507).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that my Linux machine was forgetting its username database (due to some obscure Winbind problem). As a result, Eclipse can't look up my user information and (presumably) can't find my home directory to load and parse its configuration.

(A symptom is that, when run under strace, I could see that Eclipse was looking under `?` for its `.eclipse` configuration directory.)

Fixing the username database so that Eclipse can find my user account fixed the problem. (This has also been logged on [Eclipse's Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480705).)

Comment: Is there any useful reason *why* it tries to parse it?? User's home is $HOME…

Comment: @JanHudec - I assume that Eclipse is trying to load settings out of a configuration directory under $HOME, but I didn't do further digging.

Comment: Well, that's the thing—it isn't. I do have HOME set to where I want it, but Eclipse insists on doing getpwent and using that value (which does not return anything, because it shouldn't be needed, but is).

Comment: @JanHudec - I understand what you're saying now. You're right; I don't know why Eclipse is doing that.